# where is the documentation of keras.engine.sequential.Sequential?

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
print(type(model))
```

I got <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>.

I need documentation of keras.engine.sequential.Sequential, but can't locate it.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential

Comment: @Frightera we can use `model.weights` to get model weights, in the documentation you mentioned, model has no attribute `weights`.